# Table was modified while operation was in progress, aborting execution in impala

Tags: database, hadoop, hive, impala

We’re trying to run some set of queries on impala in parallel. Both these sets work on individual set of tables. However, intermittently, they give warning: “Table was modified while operation was in progress, aborting execution.”  We tried refreshing the tables, metadata. Still finding the same issue. Any suggestions why it occurs and possible solution to avoid it?

Comment: Can you describe the workload in more detail?

Comment: My queries are not failing because of data volume . It is only when i try to run the impala scripts in parallel that i get this issue . I have tried running these scripts on different IMPALAD's but not working.

Comment: Check this link: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IMPALA-4185                     You are probably doing invalidate metadata. If yes then try adding table name to it and see if ti solves the issue.